# PNP transistor instead of mosfet to register small clock and data signals

Tags: transistors, signal, clock

I have a device that outputs -0.2v clock and data pulse (It works on CR2032 (3v) and I assume it's CMOS), I want to register that signals on arduino in simpliest way. Since no mosfets have threshold this low and since I don't want to use voltage shifter (to create dual supply) and op amp (too many elements), I tried PNP transistor and it works. Is there any sufficient risk of damaging device knowing that output will sink about 1mA of current all the time. Also, why do base have 5v when transistor is closed and how do I chose resistor values.

This is what device instruction says (is it JFET there?):

[image: instruction]

This is how I do it:

[image: schematics]

Comment: What do you mean by "-0.2v pulse"? The image seems to show a simple open drain output, with pretty comfortable specs. A simple pull-up resistor may be sufficient.

Comment: How did you determine the output of this device produces -200 mV?  I suspect you mis-measured something or got confused by something else.  At the least, this would be highly unusual.  What is the level when the pulse is not happening?

Comment: I tried to put signal directly to digital input pin with INPUT_PULLUP mode and it reads HIGH all the time and never gets LOW. I measured -200mV with osciloscope and I double checked pins and everything, when there's no pulse level is 0v, on pulse it gets 0.2V below ground.

Comment: Are you sure the ground point you are measuring from is close to the circuit ground?

Comment: Now I'm convinced there's no -0.2v actually, it must be bouncing or overshoot on the scope trace as Olin Lathrop said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're expecting 5 volt clock and data pulses out of your circuit with -0.2 volt clock and data inputs, then your circuit can't possibly work as you've drawn it.

Here's your circuit and the input and output signals:

[image]

Comment: I get it now, you're right, it can't work. This can only work if its not `0 to -0.2v` signal, but rather `disconnected to something` signal, that explains 5v on base and 0-5v that I get as a result (on scope), I got everything wrong. I will try just pullup resitor again.

Comment: Can you post the device's data sheet or a link to it, please?

Comment: Now when I know It's FET there I understand everything (I must've known or guessed, but I haven't), I connected signals straight to GPIO with internal pullup resirors activated and it works. [datasheet](http://www.produktinfo.conrad.com/datenblaetter/800000-824999/821509-an-01-ml-DIGI__MESSUHR_12_5_MM_0_01_MM_D_de_en_fr.pdf)

Comment: @mugiseyebrows: Yes; "@transistor" showed that connection on his Figure 1 (b).

Answer (score 1):

If some device puts out logic levels from -200 mV to a normal logic high level, then you probably need to do nothing special.  200 mV is well less than a diode drop.

Check the datasheet of the digital device receiving the signal.  It may be that -200 mV is within the allowed operating limits of the digital input.

As I mentioned in a comment, I'm skeptical this pulse really goes down to -200 mV.  The driving circuit would have to go out of its way to do that.  Explain how you arrived at this.  This could actually be bouncing or overshoot on the scope trace.  You should also tell us what the voltage is when the pulse is not being produced.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a device that outputs -0.2v clock and data pulse (It works on CR2032 (3v) and I assume it's CMOS) ...

This is unlikely. No-one uses -0.2 V logic.

> I want to register that signals on Arduino in simpliest way.

Your datasheet diagram shows the output as a current sinking FET. It can handle 25 V on it's top terminal and can switch up to 100 mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVM15O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) LED test circuit. (b) Arduino interface.*

The most likely problem is something simple such as a missing ground connection. The Arduino input and the LED example need a return path for the current.

If 1(b) works you can use the Arduino internal pull-up and omit R2.